# A CS-complete set is bounded

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces, normed-spaces

I will recall two definitions. Let $X$ be a normed space. One says that a subset $C\subset X$ is CS-complete (or CS-compact) if every convex series of elements of $C$ **converges** and its sum is in $C$. That is, whenever $\{x_n\}_{n \in \mathbb{N}}\subset C$ and $\{\lambda_n\}_{n \in \mathbb{N}}\subset \mathbb{F}$ are scalars such that $$\sum_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \lambda_n =1,$$ then $$\sum_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \lambda_n x_n\in C.$$

One says that a subset $C\subset X$ is CS-closed if every convex series of elements of $C$ **which converges** has its sum in $C$.

I know and I can prove that a CS-closed, bounded set in a Banach space is CS-complete and that a CS-complete set is always CS-closed. How can I prove that:

1. a CS-complete set must be bounded;
2. a CS-closed and bounded set need not be CS-complete if $X$ is not Banach?

Idea for 1. If $C$ was unbounded I would have a sequence $x_n$ of elements of $C$ with $\lvert \lvert x_n \rvert \rvert\ge n$, then ...? Can I prove that the partial sums of $\sum \lambda_n x_n$ are not close one to each other?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answer for 1): If $C$ is not bounded then there exist points $x_n$ in $C$ with $\|x_n\|>2^{n}$. Now $\sum \frac 1 {2^{n}}=1$ but $\sum \frac 1 {2^{n}} x_n$ does not converge since $\frac {x_n} {2^{n}}$ does not tend to $0$.

Answer for 2): Consider the space $\ell_0$ of all sequences which are eventually $0$ with the $\ell^{1}$ norm. Let $C$ be the closed unit ball of this space. If $(x_n) \subset C$ and  $\sum \lambda_n x_n$ converges then $\|\sum \lambda_n x_n|| \leq 1$ so $\sum \lambda_n x_n \in C$. Thus $C$ is bounded and CS-closed. However, if $e_n$ has $1$ in the $n-$th palce and $0$ elsewhere then $\sum \frac 1 {2^{n}} e_n$ does not converge in $\ell_0$.